# Recoger datos de un response.json con nodeJS

Tags: nodejs, typescript, postgresql, jsonarray

Tengo una consulta a una base de datos postgres con nodeJS y necesito sacar los datos para trabajar con ellos para una web.

```
export const getPais = async (req:Request,res:Response): Promise<Response>=> {
    try{
        const response: QueryResult = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM paises');
        return res.status(200).json(response.rows);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(500).json('Error Interno');
    }
}
```

La salida es así:

```
[
  {"id":1,"name":"Francia"},
  {"id":2,"name":"Dinamarca"},
  {"id":3,"name":"Noruega"}
]
```

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Los datos son para cargarlos en un archivo ejs, así que quizás sea más sencillo saber como cargar los datos en ese archivo desde el js...

Comment: ¿Porqué usas una [función generadora](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) cómo `callback`?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Es el código generado al compilar TS... he eliminado esa parte porque creo que no aporta nada, con el código TS es más que suficiente

Comment: @PabloLozano gracias, sólo lo he añadido por si alguien se arreglaba mejor con el código js.

Comment: ¿Y cuál sería la duda o error con tu código?

Comment: Pues que ahora tengo que saber como recorrer esos datos para ponerlo en una web en bonito. Ya he probado con esto https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application-es pero no me coge la función como variable.

Comment: ¿Habría alguna forma de cambiar el formato de datos devuelto? que, por ejemplo, devuelva una cadena en vez de un array. Quizás sería más fácil de tratar.

Comment: Vale, siguiendo el ejemplo del enlace anterior, lo que tengo que conseguir en meter el resultado del getPais en una variable para pasársela a mi ejs, ya que he probado a hacerlo igual que el ejemplo y sí que lo coge (pasando un array directamente en vez de una función).